# How to define a list length?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I was trying to define a list length with purpose to implement a streaming average - The streaming average allows you to calculate the average as you receive or process each number, without storing all the numbers in memory or calculating the sum.

The given list is termed as:

```
Ages = []
```

I attempted to define its length by writing the following line of code:

```
Ages = [0] * len(x)
```

After I had initialized the given list with a certain length (x capacity) I tried to assign numerical elements for each predefined position as seen in the given example:

```
Ages = [0] * len(x)
for i in range(0, len(random_list), 1)
    Ages.append(y[i])
```

And when I printed it I have been given with the following output:

```
print(Ages)
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 9, 3, 4, 4]
```

Unexpectedly, `Ages` has expanded its capacity by adding both, x and y lengths.

How to populate the given list without expanding its capacity?

Comment: What are x and y here? You created a list of length `len(x)` and appended one item `len(random_list)` times to it, so the final length is `len(x) + len(random_list)`.

Comment: `.append` appends further elements to the list. A default `list` cannot be “initialised” nor size limited; it’s just there and you keep stuffing items into it, or remove them.

Comment: To assign a value to position `i` in `Ages` (assuming it is already at least as long), write `Ages[i] = value`, not `Ages.append(value)`.

Comment: Or maybe you meant to start with an empty list and keep appending values to it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a list at all to implement an average generator.  Just keep track of the current average and count of items so far:

```
def streamAVG(source):
    average = 0
    for count,value in enumerate(source,1):
        average = (average*(count-1) + value)/count
        yield average
```

You can feed an iterator (or iterable) to this generator and it will spit out the current (streaming) average as you go:

```
stream = iter(range(5,10))

for avg in streamAVG(stream):
    print(avg)

5.0
5.5
6.0
6.5
7.0
```

If you were meaning to implement a rolling average, then you would need a list (or a FIFO queue):

```
def rollingAVG(source,window):
    values  = [0]*window
    total   = 0
    for count,value in enumerate(source,1):
        total += value - values[count%window]
        values[count%window] = value
        yield total/min(window,count)

stream = iter(range(5,10))

for avg in rollingAVG(stream,3):
    print(avg)

5.0
5.5
6.0
7.0
8.0
```

*Notice how `values[count%window] = value` assigns a value to an existing position in the list that was set-up using `values = [0]*window`  This changes the item that is already there, as opposed to `values.append(...)` which would increase the size of the list by "appending" a new item at the end.  Using the modulo division `%` on the list size (window) makes the item index loop over the existing items going around and back to the same position after cycling through every position.*

Comment: this is a good answer, but given the relatively basic misunderstanding the OP has about lists, you may want to at least talk about the difference between `.append` and indexed assignment.